# How to force-stop the application programatically-Android

Tags: android

I want to force-stop an application from my android app, (Instead of doing manually by Man apps->force-stop). How to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

```
Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this implementation to findout the process id and kill it.

```
int pid;
ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> pids = am.getRunningAppProcesses();
   for(int i = 0; i < pids.size(); i++)
   {
       ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo info = pids.get(i);
       if(info.processName.equalsIgnoreCase("com.yourapp.app")){
          pid = info.pid;
       } 
   }
android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
```

Comment: From Google documentation: void android.os.Process.killProcess(int pid)

Kill the process with the given PID. Note that, though this API allows us to request to kill any process based on its PID, the kernel will still impose standard restrictions on which PIDs you are actually able to kill. Typically this means only the process running the caller's packages/application and any additional processes created by that app; packages sharing a common UID will also be able to kill each other's processes.