# How to force close app such as system close on Android

Tags: android, forceclose

I want to force close my app as Android system.
Such as select below step on system.

```
"Setting" -> "Apps" -> "my app name" -> "Force stop"
```

I want to implement the same behavior by code.
How can I do it?

Comment: use this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8254199/how-to-force-stop-the-application-programatically-android

Comment: But why would you do this?

Comment: I only want to add a force close app button for user.

Comment: Why not just add a 'close' button and finish all your activities cleanly instead of force closing the app?

Comment: Why not do the "Android" thing and NOT have a close button?  99% of apps don't need one and it's frustrating that so many apps waste screen estate and who knows hide what coding horrors behind close buttons.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can write below line of code to kill your App process. This is what the code runs when you click the Force Stop in

> Settings --> Manage Applications

```
android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
```

Comment: thank you TNR. It does the trick. But, it redirects the user to the first activity of our application(I think it restarts our application). Is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: @ShivanandDarur You'll want to call 'finish();' after that to deal with closing that one Activity.

Answer (score 2):

You can use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html to kill your application process.

Answer (score 1):

yes its is possible you have to call `public static final void killProcess (int pid)`
Kill the process with the given PID. Note that, though this API allows us to request to kill any process based on its PID, the kernel will still impose standard restrictions on which PIDs you are actually able to kill. Typically this means only the process running the caller's packages/application and any additional processes created by that app; packages sharing a common UID will also be able to kill each other's processes.

Answer (score 0):

There are force closes and there are force closes. The killProcess does a trick most of the time but there are cases when it is not enough (broadcast messages, for example).

To kill an app completely and for good, simply add the following method to your activity and call it. What this actually does will be left for the reader as an exercise. :)

```
@SuppressWarnings("null")
public void crash() {
    Object o = null;
    o.hashCode();
}
```

Super dirty, yes. But useful if, for example, you really need to simulate a force close (like I do).